# How to hide only scrollbar thumb on Bootsrap modal?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

On bootstrap [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#vertically-centered) when you open a `modal` it does only hide the `scrollbar thumb`.
 
 
[image]
[image]

But my `modal` hide the whole scrollbar. How can I do it like the examples and hide only `scrollbar thumb`?

```css
body {
  height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: just u  want scroll bar track not thumb i'm right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its Already working in your demo, if you inspect it you'll find `padding-right: 17px` in body when opening modal

what the modal do is: hiding the overflow, so that no scrollbar won't be shown. and adding the right padding of 17px (the width of scrollbar).

the trick is in bootstrap website there is another scrollbar in the right. So you will think that there is scrollbar without thumb but actually there is not scrollbar at all, it's only `padding-right`

There is some workaround by adding bar when the modal is opened, positioned in the same place of the scrollbar. by using jquery and events provided by bootstrap modal ([See the link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/))

```js
$("#exampleModalCenter").on("show.bs.modal", function() {
  $(".scroll").addClass("show")
});
$("#exampleModalCenter").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
  $(".scroll").removeClass("show")
});
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 1200px
}
.scroll {
display: none;
}
.scroll.show { 
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
width: 17px;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
<div class="scroll"></div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there any easy way to achieve the same effect without having another scrollbar in the right?

Comment: @SilverSurfer I've updated the answer, you can check the solution